# How to display text to the right of a div inside another div?

Tags: html, css, text, text-alignment

I'm having a problem with the set text to the right of a div
It is always at the bottom, not on the right.
Here is my code

```css
.player-container {
    position: relative;
    text-align: right;
    line-break: auto;
    display: inline-block;
    left: 0;
}

.player-container h1 {
    position: absolute;
    margin: 0 auto;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    text-align: center;
    width: 60%;
}

.player-container .model {
    padding-top: 3rem;
    width: 700px;
    height: 450px;
}

.player-about {
    display: inline-block;
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="page-content">
        <div class="player" label="END">
            <div class="player-container">
                <h1 class="username">END</h1>
                <model-viewer class="model" src="assets/scene.gltf" alt="VR Headset" auto-rotate camera-controls ar
                    ios-src="assets/scene.gltf">
                </model-viewer>
            </div>
            <p class="player_about"> text
            </p>
        </div>
    </div>
```

My result:
[image]

What I want:[image]

How to display text to the right of a div inside another div?
Is there any solution that will work for me?

Comment: You just have a typo: In your CSS it is `player-about` and in your HTML it is `player_about` with an underline character.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One solution is to turn `.player` into a flex container:

```
.player {
    display: flex;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

alternatively, you can use `display: flex` by adding `.player` selector

```css
.player-container {
    position: relative;
    text-align: right;
    line-break: auto;
    display: inline-block;
    left: 0;
}

.player-container h1 {
    position: absolute;
    margin: 0 auto;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    text-align: center;
    width: 60%;
}

.player-container .model {
    padding-top: 3rem;
    width: 700px;
    height: 450px;
}

.player {
    display: flex;
}
```

```html
<div class="page-content">
    <div class="player" label="END">
        <div class="player-container">
            <h1 class="username">END</h1>
            <model-viewer class="model" src="assets/scene.gltf" alt="VR Headset" auto-rotate camera-controls ar
                ios-src="assets/scene.gltf">
            </model-viewer>
        </div>
        <p class="player-about"> text
        </p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You used a different class (probably a typo) for your `<p>` where it's `player_about` in the html and `player-about` in css.